# Algorithm accepting every passphrase to fool unlegit user

Tags: algorithm-design, deniable-encryption, plausible-deniability

I'm looking for specific names and literature on crypto algorithms that accept every passphrase input by the user, in order to 'decrypt' - even with false passphrase - and present the unlegit user with a false plaintext. The unlegit user should not be able to determine whether the 'decrypted' text is real or fake - as it accepts every passphrase.

Of course using the legit passphrase reveals the legit plaintext.

I found two examples of what I mean:
The Fraunhofer Institut in Germany invented a smartphone password-manager app that uses this kind of technology. Its called iMobileSitter. And I think on Eurocrypt2014 a paper called 'Honey Encryption' with a  similar algorithm has been submitted.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2272/991 $\;$

Comment: There is no question here, and reference requests are offtopic. Beside it is pretty close to Ricky's question; although I wouldn't tag it as a duplicate

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/honeywords/) recent work from MIT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the exact status of the program, since there was some controversy surrounding it a few weeks ago, see: [Is TrueCrypt not secure now and should I stop using it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58940/is-truecrypt-not-secure-now-and-should-i-stop-using-it). But the very popular program [TrueCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truecrypt), a program is typically used to encrypt stored files and drives, I believe has the property that you are asking about. Its called: [Plausible Deniablility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plausible_deniability). So combine the concept of plausible deniablility with strong crypto and you have [Deniable Encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption)

A passage from the page on deniable encryption states:

> Normally ciphertexts decrypt to a single plaintext and hence once
>   decrypted, the encryption user cannot claim that he encrypted a
>   different message. Deniable encryption allows its users to decrypt the
>   ciphertext to produce a different (innocuous but plausible) plaintext
>   and insist that it is what they encrypted. The holder of the
>   ciphertext will not have the means to differentiate between the true
>   plaintext, and the bogus-claim plaintext.

How TrueCrypt implements this, is basically by allowing you to make hidden partitions on a hard drive, and have "fake" partitions to fool attackers.

Comment: Plausible Deniable Encryption from Truecrypt seems like a 'light' version of the algorithms I mean. Because these algorithms accept *any* password and fool the attacker by display a 'valid looking cleartext'. All password inputs by the attacker will trigger decryption.

Comment: Seems to me like the attacker would easily figure this out and know that it was a scheme to fool the attacker (e.g. easy to google to find threads like this one). This does not happen with TC's approach.